# How can I correct my email-id in postman account?

Tags: postman

I have somehow incorrect email id in my postman account (*********@gmail.**ocm** instead of *********@gmail.**com**). How can I rectify this? As email id itself is incorrect how I can get any link to update email id?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you sign up with your correct email?

or maybe I don't understand your question :D could you look into account settings? Maybe there is smth there helpful https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/postman-account/